# Add wxs file to product.wxs file in wix 3.8

Tags: wix, windows-installer, setup-deployment

need to add Files.wxs file in to Product.wxs file

i added the using include command(include Files.wxs)

this gives and error

Error   1 The Wix element contains an unsupported extension element 'Include'.  The Wix element does not currently support extension elements. Is the Include element using the correct XML namespace?

added this for create buldevents

"$(WixToolPath)heat.exe" dir "project path" -var var.SourceDir -gg -sfrag -scom -sreg -suid -t "$(ProjectDir)TransformDirectoryToWix.xslt" -out "$(ProjectDir)Files.wxs

any way to solve this?

Comment: Just a guess but you might want to try this with WiX 3.6. Or, re-approach the while project using current techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Something seems fishy here.

You use include for other `WXI` files. You don't need to include wxs files with each other.

If you want to reference element that resides in another wxs file, you set ID's and use: *DirectoryRef*, *ComponentRef*, *ComponentGroupRef*, etc..

Check out ComponentGroupRef: http://chriseelmaa.com/harvesting-files-with-wix-heat/

Comment: Thansk for your reply on this. i refered this example for deployment in IIS.  http://mstechblogger.blogspot.com/2011/06/installing-web-application-using-wix.html

Comment: @Erti-Chris Eelmaa - your link is dead